# Wix: Localizing the bal:condtion in bundle.wxs by modifying mbapreq.wxl for custom ManagedBootstrapperApplicationHost

Tags: localization, wix, bootstrapper

I have made a custom bootstrapper application. I have customized the mbapreq.thm and mbapreq.wxl for custom UI.

My bundle.wxs looks like this.

```
 <BootstrapperApplicationRef Id="ManagedBootstrapperApplicationHost">

  <Payload Name="1031\mbapreq.wxl" SourceFile="de\mbapreq.wxl" />
  <Payload Name="1036\mbapreq.wxl" SourceFile="fr\mbapreq.wxl" />
  <Payload Name="1041\mbapreq.wxl" SourceFile="ja\mbapreq.wxl" />
  <Payload Name="2052\mbapreq.wxl" SourceFile="zh-CN\mbapreq.wxl" />
  <Payload Name="3082\mbapreq.wxl" SourceFile="es\mbapreq.wxl" />
  <Payload Name="mbapreq.thm" SourceFile="mbapreq.thm" />
 </BootstrapperApplicationRef>

<bal:Condition
  Message="!(loc.OSNOTSUPPORTED)">
  (VersionNT >= v6.0)
</bal:Condition>

<Fragment>
<WixVariable Id ="PreqbaThemeWxl" Value="mbapreq.wxl"/>
<WixVariable Id ="PreqbaThemeXml" Value="mbapreq.thm"/>
</Fragment>
```

I have included OSNOTSUPPORTED in mbapreq.wxl also.

`<String Id="OSNOTSUPPORTED">This application is only supported on Windows Server 2003 (32 and 64bit), Windows 2008 (32 and 64bit) and Windows 2008 R2 (Windows 7) or higher.</String>`

Same string OSNOTSUPPORTED are added for other languages also.
I have also including "-loc mbapreq.wxl" into make file.

When I run my application UI is getting changed as per mbapreq.thm for all the languages.
But UI is reflecting "OSNOTSUPPORTED" as per english language only even when running application in other languages (With -lang 1031 parameter).

So anyone could help how to localize the bal:condition ??

Answer (score 1):

I believe the issue is incorrect variable type as you want to find the theme text
`!` is used for linker
`#` is used for runtime theme

```
<bal:Condition Message="#(loc.OSNOTSUPPORTED)">
```